# Mysql match against alternative

Tags: mysql, match, against

I need a search with a relevance algorithm and the database is mysql. I have to sort the results by date, if keyword is in title or not, number of apparitions of the keyword in  the text and so on.

Match against doesn't give me that much control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would do what you want:

```
select
  * 
from
  myTable
order by
  sum
  (
    itemdate='2009-10-09',
    title like '%keyword%',
    text like '%keyword%', 
    criteria4,
    criteria5
  )
```

- Each criteria returns 0 if false, and 1 if true.
- You sum each of those and order by the result.
- Rows that have the most matching criteria will be on top.

You can finetune all this of course by not just having 0 or 1 per criteria.

Comment: Am I the only one who get the mistake 1046?

Comment: @Micha93: yes, you probably are. :-) You're probably referring to MySQL error 1046. It means that you did not select a database. Do that in your client, or first run something like `USE my_database;`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve

Answer (score -4):

```
select
  * 
from
  myTable
order by
(
    (itemdate='2009-10-09') +
    (title like '%keyword%') +
    (text like '%keyword%') +
    (criteria4) +
    (criteria5)
)
```

This works really great.

Comment: Sorry, but `SELECT *` without a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause is not my idea of "works really great"