# Error 1046 No database selected, how to resolve?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mysqlcommand, mysql-error-1046

Error
SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `work`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `administrators`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `administrators` (

`user_id` varchar( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` varchar( 30 ) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

need some help here.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, you can also specify the database name via the CLI command without editing the import file.  `mysql -u root -p databasename < import.sql`

Comment: what happened to me was: create a schema, filled in the name of the database, then it says "fail, no database selected". reopen workbench, i see database that i have just failed to created. Then I choose the database that i have just created, and open a .sql file and run, with both create database and use database statements, it complains "fail no database selected" again. reopen workbench, the tables are all built. MAC system, workbench 6.3.3

Comment: Remember if you are on *nix systems and your database name has a $, wrap the name with single quotes.

Answer (score 595):

You need to tell MySQL which database to use:

```
USE database_name;
```

before you create a table.

In case the database does not exist, you need to create it as:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

followed by:

```
USE database_name;
```

Comment: In my case, I had used mysqldump to export a database and was running into this upon import. I just had to edit the exported sql file to add these two commands to the top of it.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. I had a script to create my database and tables but the tables weren't getting created because I needed to insert the `USE tablename` command.

Comment: Write:
`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database_name ;`
`USE database_name;`
This works whether the database is already created or not.

Comment: `USE database_name` make selected database as default but what if you want to use other than you have run it again right?

Answer (score 67):

You can also tell MySQL what database to use (if you have it created already):

```
 mysql -u example_user -p --database=example < ./example.sql
```

Comment: Why not `mysql example -u example_user -p < ./example.sql` instead?

Answer (score 43):

I faced the same error when I tried to import a database created from before.  Here is what I did to fix this issue:

1. Create new database
2. Use it by `use` command

[image]

3. Try again

Comment: one more note - make sure that the jdbc connection string contains the schema name and that schema is created already.

Answer (score 33):

### If you're trying to do this via the command line...

If you're trying to run the CREATE TABLE statement from the command line interface, you need to specify the database you're working in before executing the query:

```
USE your_database;
```

Here's [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html).

### If you're trying to do this via MySQL Workbench...

...you need to select the appropriate database/catalog in the drop down menu found above the :Object Browser: tab. You can specify the default schema/database/catalog for the connection - click the "Manage Connections" options under the SQL Development heading of the Workbench splash screen.

### Addendum

This all assumes there's a database you want to create the table inside of - if not, you need to create the database before anything else:

```
CREATE DATABASE your_database;
```

Comment: Using MySQL Workbench: Could you please provide an image with the location of the drop down?

Comment: I'm thinking this might refer to an older version of MySQL Workbench. I just pulled the most current version and I don't see an "object browser" tab anywhere.

Comment: Looks like you need to use the `USE database;` command, even in MySQL Workbench (I'm in v5.2.47) if you're getting this error. Only need to run it one time per query tab - all subsequent executions on that tab seem to use the database correctly.

Comment: Hi, So for wordpress sql how can we "use" in SQL file. Can you please clarify that once more. I am having the issue now.

Answer (score 25):

If you are doing this through phpMyAdmin:

- I'm assuming you already Created a new MySQL Database on Live Site (by live site I mean the company your hosting with (in my case Bluehost)).
- Go to phpMyAdmin on live site - log in to the database you just created.
- Now IMPORTANT! Before clicking the "import" option on the top bar, select your database on the left side of the page (grey bar, on the top has PHP Myadmin written, below it two options:information_schema and name of database you just logged into.
- Once you click the database you just created/logged into it will show you that database and then click the import option.

Comment: You'd think that if you weren't already on the database, there would be an option on the page to allow you to select one.

Comment: The best answer and simple, u need to select the database table at the left after logging into the database on live server

Answer (score 25):

**For MySQL Workbench**

1. Select database from Schemas tab by right mouse clicking.
2. Set database as Default Schema

[image]

Comment: In MySQL Workbench 8.0, you have to select your Default Schema to be Imported to in the Data Import window.

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you are using the command line:

#### 1. Find Database

`show databases;`

[image: Example of a database list]

#### 2. Select a database from the list

e.g. `USE classicmodels;` and you should be off to the races! (Obviously, you'll have to use the correctly named database in your list.

#### Why is this error occurring?

Mysql requires you to select the particular database you are working on. I presume it is a design decision they made: it avoids a lot of potential problems: e.g. it is entirely possible, for you to use the same table names across multiple databases e.g. a `users` table. In order to avoid these types of issues, they probably thought: "let's make users select the database they want".

Answer (score 15):

- Edit your `SQL` file using **Notepad** or **Notepad++**
- Add the following 2 lines:

  ```
  CREATE DATABASE NAME;
  USE NAME;
  ```

Comment: How can we write in case for wordpress database file as am trying to import using MySql Workbench but getting no database selected

Answer (score 10):

If importing a database, you need to create one first with the same name, then select it and then IMPORT the existing database to it.

Comment: Please add some detail on your answer explaining your steps.

Answer (score 5):

Check you have created the database first which you want.

If you have not created the dataBase you have to fire this query:

```
CREATE DATABASE data_base_name
```

If you have already created the database then you can simply fire this query and you will be able to create table on your database:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_base_name`.`table_name` (
 _id int not null,
 LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 FirstName varchar(255),
 Age int,
 PRIMARY KEY (_id)
);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Solution with an Example**

- Error `1046` occurs when we miss to connect our table with a database. In this case, we don't have any database and that’s why at first we will create a new database and then will instruct to use that database for the created table.

```
# At first you have to create Database 
CREATE DATABASE student_sql;

# Next, specify the database to use
USE student_sql;

# Demo: create a table 
CREATE TABLE student_table(
    student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    major VARCHAR(20)
);

# Describe the table 
describe student_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting ivan n :
"If importing a database, you need to create one first with the same name, then select it and then IMPORT the existing database to it.
Hope it works for you!"

These are the steps:
Create a Database, for instance my_db1, utf8_general_ci.
Then click to go inside this database.
Then click "import", and select the database: my_db1.sql

Comment: This should be a comment underneath Ivan's answer, so he can change his answer to include your steps.

Answer (score 2):

In Amazon RDS, merely writing `use my-favorite-database` does not work if that database's name includes dashes. Furthermore, none of the following work, either:

```
use "my-favorite-database"
use `my-favorite-database`
use 'my-favorite-database'
```

Just click the "Change Database" button, select the desired database, and voilà.

Answer (score 1):

First select database : USE db_name

Then creat table:CREATE TABLE tb_name
(
id  int,
name varchar(255),
salary int,
city varchar(255)
);

This is for MySQL 5.5 version syntax

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for the solution when this error occurs with `mysqldump` instead of mysql, try this solution that I found on a German website out there by chance.

So the problem occurs because the lack `-databases` parameter before the database name

So your command must look like this:

```
mysqldump -pdbpass -udbuser --databases dbname
```

Another cause of the problem in my case was that I'm developing on local and the `root` user doesn't have a password, so in this case you must use `--password=` instead of `-pdbpass`, so my final command was:

```
mysqldump -udbuser --password= --databases dbname
```

---

Link to the complete thread (in German) : https://marius.bloggt-in-braunschweig.de/2016/04/29/solution-mysqldump-no-database-selected-when-selecting-the-database/

Answer (score 1):

Simple

1. click on database
2. and then click on import

without modifying .sql file

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

When I ran these SQL below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM person;
```

Or:

```sql
SHOW EVENTS;
```

So, I selected `apple` database with [use(USE)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html) as shown below, then the error was solved. *You can omit `;`:

```
use apple;
```

Or:

```
USE apple;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a pretty old thread, I just found something out. I created a new database, then added a user, and finally went to use phpMyAdmin to upload the .sql file.  total failure.  The system doesn't recognize which DB I'm aiming at...

When I start fresh WITHOUT first attaching a new user, and then perform the same phpMyAdmin import, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add: If you create a database in mySQL on a live site, then go into PHPMyAdmin and the database isn't showing up - logout of cPanel then log back in, open PHPMyAdmin, and it should be there now.

Answer (score 0):

For an added element of safety, when working with multiple DBs in the same script you can specify the DB in the query, e.g. "create table my_awesome_db.really_cool_table...".

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a new DB in MySQL.
2. Select that new DB (if you are using MySQL phpmyadmin now on the top it'll be like 'Server:***.**.*.* >> Database ).
3. Now go to import tab select file.Import!