# What is a procedure in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, stored-procedures, mysql-routines

I've Googled but come up with nothing that I can get my head around.

Are the performance gains from using stored procedures significant?

Would I still want to use prepared statements in conjunction with stored procs or is it generally a one or the other thing?

Can I create stored procs through PHPMyAdmin and manage them from there as well?

What would a stored procedure look like for something simple like this-

```
SELECT * FROM table a 
INNER JOIN otherTable b 
ON a.join_id=b.join_id 
WHERE someVar = :boundParam
```

and how would the PHP work (PDO) to call it and bind its parameter?

Comment: no contest - sprocs are more efficient on so many levels. Let's forget query optimisation and execution speed - let's think in terms of calls required, bytes sent..., grants required (exec vs all), security, how many calls does mysqli/pdo need to make to exec 1 parameterised query ? would that be 2 ??? lol

Answer (score 0):

#### A [procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html):

- can have zero or more SQL statements with [BEGIN ... END statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html). *No statement without `BEGIN ... END` statement gets error.
- can have only single statement without `BEGIN ... END` statement not changing the delimiter to `$$` without error.
- can have multiple parameters with `IN`, `OUT` and `INOUT` and without them.
- can get zero or more values with zero or more `IN` and `INOUT` parameters from the caller.
- can return zero or more values to the caller with `OUT` and `INOUT` parameters.
- can have [local variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html) and [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference/77675418#77675418) explains local variables and user-defined variables.
- can have [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html).
- cannot have [RETURN statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/return.html#:%7E:text=The%20RETURN%20statement%20terminates%20execution,procedures%2C%20triggers%2C%20or%20events.) otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199113/error-1313-return-is-only-allowed-in-a-function-when-creating-a-stored-proced#77662587).
- is not atomic by default so if there is error, it is not rollbacked automatically. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092508/are-procedures-atomic-in-mysql/77668730#77668730) explains it in detail.

*In this answer, I explain how to create a procedure with an `IN` parameter and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635092/what-is-the-purpose-of-out-in-mysql-stored-procedures/77524876#77524876) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579058/inout-parameter-for-a-mysql-procedure/77525443#77525443) explain `OUT` and `INOUT` parameters respectively and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) explains a procedure in detail.

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num int
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `2` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (2);
```

Now, you can create `addition(IN value INT)` procedure which adds `value` to `num` as shown below. *The `IN` parameter `IN value INT` can get the value from the caller and you can also use `value INT` without `IN` which is also recognized as an `IN` parameter and basically, you need to change the default delimiter `;` to something like `$$` when creating a procedure otherwise there is error, then after creating a procedure, you need to change the delimiter `$$` back to `;` as shown below and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259504/delimiters-in-mysql/77440483#77440483) explains delimiter and you must select a database when creating a procedure otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve/77491814#77491814):

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addition(IN value INT)
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + value;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addition(INOUT v1 INT, INOUT v2 INT)
BEGIN
SELECT v1+1, v2+1 into v1, v2;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you can call `addition(3)` with [CALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html) statement, then `3` is added to `num` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> CALL addition(3);
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  5   |
+------+
```

Or, you can set [the user-defined session variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) e.g. `@v` with `3`, then `3` is added to `num` as shown below. *The initial value of a user-defined session variable is `NULL`:

```sql
mysql> SET @v = 3;
...
mysql> CALL addition(@v);
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  5   |
+------+
```

In addition, you can create `addition()` procedure with the user-defined session variable e.g. `@v` and without an `IN` parameter as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addition()
BEGIN                    -- ↓↓ Here
UPDATE test SET num = num + @v;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you set `@v` with `3` and call `addition()`, then `3` is added to `num` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SET @v = 3;
...
mysql> CALL addition();
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  5   |
+------+
```

And, in this case below, you can create `addition(IN value INT)` procedure not changing the delimiter to `$$` without error:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE addition(IN value INT)
UPDATE test SET num = num + value;
```

Comment: I wonder if this answer would have been better placed on one of the duplicates, especially considering that another, well-upvoted, answer to this question has been deleted.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I find the checkers related to database are strange, mean, close-minded, unreasonable or too strict. I ofter answer Python's questions and the checkers related to Python are good, open-minded and reasonable.