# Stored procedures IN, OUT, INOUT parameters in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database, stored-procedures, parameters

Can anyone give me a detailed explanation of the difference between `IN`, `OUT`, and `INOUT` parameters?

Thanks.

P.S.
I'm using MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 7):

**1. IN**

```
    mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE in_2(IN value INT )BEGIN SELECT value; SET value =100;SE
    LECT value;END//
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

     mysql> SET @s =9//
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> CALL in_2(@s)//
    +-------+
    | value |
    +-------+
    |     9 |
    +-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

    +-------+
    | value |
    +-------+
    |   100 |
    +-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @s;
    -> //
+------+
| @s   |
+------+
|    9 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2.OUT**

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE in_3(OUT value INT)
    -> SET value=100//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @x=56//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL in_3(@x)//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @x//
+------+
| @x   |
+------+
|  100 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what about `INOUT`?

Answer (score 5):

IN parameters are passed in to the SP by value.
OUT parameters are returned from the SP by value.
INOUT parameters are passed by reference, since they contain one value going in and another coming out.

Comment: The last part is not true in SQL Server.

Comment: Well that's the way it's done in LINQ2SQL, anyway. You may be right. I thought it was more general.

Comment: Just read your link, it referes to TSQL. Since the asker does not specify a language, my answer is more general, I think.

Comment: @EladLachmi what is mentioned by SP in your answer

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya - Stored Procedure

Answer (score 1):

Um, in parameters receive data from their caller. out parameters push data to their caller (call-by-reference). inout parameters do both. I'm not sure how to make this more detailed without a clearer idea of what it is you want to know.

Comment: Then tell us which database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

An `IN` parameter (e.g. `IN value INT`) can get the value from the caller and you can also use `value INT` without `IN` which is also recognized as an `IN` parameter. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278392/what-is-a-procedure-in-mysql/77517648#77517648) explains how to create a procedure with an `IN` parameter.

An `OUT` parameter:

- can return the value from a procedure to the caller with [a user-defined session variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) .
- cannot accept a raw value without using a user-defined session variable from the caller.
- cannot get any value from the caller because the initial value of an `OUT` parameter is always `NULL` within the procedure.

  *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635092/what-is-the-purpose-of-out-in-mysql-stored-procedures/77524876#77524876) explains how to create a procedure with an `OUT` parameter.

An `INOUT` parameter:

- can get the value from the caller and return the value from a procedure to the caller with a user-defined session variable.
- cannot accept a raw value without using a user-defined session variable from the caller.

  *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579058/inout-parameter-for-a-mysql-procedure/77525443#77525443) explains how to create a procedure with an `INOUT` parameter.