# `INOUT` parameter for a MySQL procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, database, stored-procedures, inout

Could you please give me a simple example of `INOUT` in MySQL stored procedure?

Answer (score 6):

I think searching Google will give you tons of examples!!
One (taken from [here](http://www.joeyrivera.com/2009/using-mysql-stored-procedure-inout-and-recordset-w-php/))

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`get_users` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_users`(
    IN firstName VARCHAR(100),
    OUT totalUsers INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO totalUsers
    FROM users
    WHERE first_name = firstName;
    SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE first_name = firstName;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Post says:

> Notice there are two statements in the body of this stored procedure.
>   The first select count(*) statement counts the total number of people
>   who’s first name is equal to the in variable firstName. Once it’s gets
>   the count, it sets the out variable totalUsers to that value.
>
> The next
>   statement is a simple select. This will select all fields for users
>   who’s first name is equal to the in variable firstName and return the
>   recordset. So by calling this stored procedure and passing in two
>   parameters (first name, total), a recordset will be returned and an
>   out variable will be set – that can then be queried.

**EDITED:**
As in [MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p (OUT ver_param VARCHAR(25), INOUT incr_param INT)
BEGIN
  # Set value of OUT parameter
  SELECT VERSION() INTO ver_param;
  # Increment value of INOUT parameter
  SET incr_param = incr_param + 1;
END;
```

Comment: Is there a procedure something like CREATE PROCEDURE `Capitalize`(INOUT str VARCHAR(1024)) ? Can you see INOUT? Whats the difference between this INOUT and yours with IN and OUT combination? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user1251490: `IN` means input only, `OUT` means output only, `INOUT` means both input and output. Look at my example taken from MySQL website.

Comment: @user1251490: did you find my post useful?

Answer (score 5):

### Example of INOUT usage in MySQL:

From the terminal run `mysql -u root -p`.

```
el@apollo:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

Change to your database:

```
mysql> use yourdb;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
```

Create a variable to feed into your stored procedure called `msg`.

```
mysql> select 'ricksays' into @msg;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Create the stored procedure:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create procedure foobar (inout msg varchar(100))
-> begin
-> set msg = concat(@msg, " never gonna let you down");
-> end//
```

Set the delimiter back:

```
mysql> delimiter ;
```

Invoke the stored procedure, pass in the variable.

```
mysql> call foobar(@msg);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Ok, Now see if it worked:

```
mysql> select @msg;
+-----------------------------------+
| @msg                              |
+-----------------------------------+
| ricksays never gonna let you down |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ok it worked, it joined the strings together.  So you defined a variable msg, passed in that variable into stored procedure called foobar, and @msg was written to by foobar.

Which is the purpose of the INOUT parameter.  You could use this to solve problems.

Answer (score 3):

If like me, the confusion was the difference between OUT and INOUT. Which was clarified with these points found in the MySQL Certification Study Guide

> OUT - Any value the parameter has when it is passed is ignored by the
>   procedure, and its initial value within the procedure is NULL
>
> INOUT - The value passed by the caller is the parameter's initial
>   value within the procedure

Answer (score 0):

An `INOUT` parameter:

- can get the value from the caller and return the value from a procedure to the caller with [a user-defined session variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).
- cannot accept a raw value without using a user-defined session variable from the caller.

*[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278392/what-is-a-procedure-in-mysql/77517648#77517648) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635092/what-is-the-purpose-of-out-in-mysql-stored-procedures/77524876#77524876) explains an `IN` and `OUT` parameters respectively and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) explains an `INOUT` parameter.

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num int
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `2` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (2);
```

Now, you can create `addition(INOUT result INT)` procedure which adds `result` to `num` and returns `num` value with `result` to the caller as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addition(INOUT result INT)
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + result;
SELECT num INTO result FROM test;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you can set `3` to the user-defined session variable e.g. `@r`, then call `addition(@r)` with [CALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html) statement, then `3` is added to `num` and `@r` has `num` value `5` as shown below. *The initial value of a user-defined session variable is `NULL`:

```sql
mysql> SET @r = 3;
...
mysql> CALL addition(@r);
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|   5  |
+------+
...
mysql> SELECT @r;
+------+
| @r   |
+------+
|   5  |
+------+
```

Be careful, passing the raw value `3` to `result` parameter gets [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751707/mysql-not-a-variable-or-new-pseudo-variable-message/77526195#77526195) below because as I say above, an `INOUT` parameter cannot accept a raw value without using a user-defined session variable from the caller.

```sql
mysql> CALL addition(3);
ERROR 1414 (42000): OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine apple.addition is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
```

In addition, you can create `addition()` procedure with the user-defined session variable e.g. `@r` and without an `INOUT` parameter as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addition()
BEGIN                    -- ↓↓ Here
UPDATE test SET num = num + @r;
SELECT num INTO @r FROM test;
END$$        -- ↑↑ Here

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you set `@r` with `3` and call `addition()`, then `3` is added to `num` and `@r` has `num` value `5` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SET @r = 3;
...
mysql> CALL addition();
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
...
mysql> SELECT @r;
+------+
| @r   |
+------+
|   5  |
+------+
```