# MySQL "not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable" message

Tags: sql, mysql, database, stored-procedures, out

I'm trying to create a procedure that will enter data and then return a message in the OUT parameter, however i'm getting this message "argument 5 for routine hospital.alextest10 is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger"

I have this as my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE alextest10
(IN a_patid CHAR(3), IN a_patnam VARCHAR(12), IN a_consno CHAR(3), IN a_ward CHAR(2),
OUT a_message VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SET a_message = 'Database updated';
INSERT INTO patient (patient_id, patient_name, consultant_no, ward_no)
VALUES (a_patid, a_patnam, a_consno, a_ward);
END!
```

And, this is my call command:

```
CALL alextest10 ('p99', 'Madeuppy', '999', 'w9', a_message)!
```

Can you help?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
CALL alextest10 ('p99', 'Madeuppy', '999', 'w9', @a_message);
SELECT @a_message;
```

Comment: this gets rid of the error message, but it's not bringing up the message, just adding the data. any ideas?

Comment: brilliant :) i thought the function did something else. working perfectly now, thank you both very much

Comment: how did you declare @a_message variable?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi : were you able to figure out ?

Comment: @j10 sorry bro, don't remember now.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi You don't declare user-defined variables, you just start using them. [See here](/a/11754790).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1414 (42000): OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine apple.addition is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

When I called `addition` procedure which has the `OUT` or `INOUT` parameters `result` with the raw value `3` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE addition(OUT result INT)
...
mysql> CALL addition(3);
```

Or:

```sql
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE addition(INOUT result INT)
...
mysql> CALL addition(3);
```

So, I called `addition` procedure with [the user-defined session variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) `@r` as shown below, then I could call `addition` procedure without error. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635092/what-is-the-purpose-of-out-in-mysql-stored-procedures/77524876#77524876) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579058/inout-parameter-for-a-mysql-procedure/77525443#77525443) explain `OUT` and `INOUT` parameters respectively:

```sql
mysql> CALL addition(@r);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use **registerOutParameter** - in your case:

```
cStmt.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

where type of *cStmt* is *CallableStatement*.

Comment: This question does not mention Java at all.