# Returning a value from a MySQL Stored Procedure when completed

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

Currently I have a stored procedure which works fine without the out variable, but i wanted to put one in so that i can ensure that my code on the Delphi Application does no run until the Stored Procedure has finished.

Can someone see if I have done this right as i keep getting an error regarding out not being a variable. Is anyone able to explain this?

Please see below my code I am using.

DELIMITER $$

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_moveToWizconTemp`(
OUT success int)
BEGIN

//Code to do some processing and end of SP Processing

SET success = 1;

END
```

Regards,

Jordan

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Had to add a $$ on the END. How are you calling this?

Comment: The error I am facing @RonakShah is:

Error Code: 1414. OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine taglogging.proc_moveToWizconTemp is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Comment: I'm calling this in MySQL at the moment but will be calling it from a Delphi7 Application @Giles

Comment: Sorry, I meant could you actually give us the command you are using. Also, found this which may be duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751707/mysql-not-a-variable-or-new-pseudo-variable-message

Comment: The problem seems to be the connector used from Delphi. What connector and version are you using, maybe [Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)?

Comment: Im using command:
CALL taglogging.proc_moveToWizconTemp(); in the MySQL Workbench interface. @Giles

Comment: Hi @wchiquito, Im using ADOConnector(ADODB) in Delphi 7 :)

Comment: Sorry for slow reply - You need a variable in the () in that call for the OUT value to go in to.