# How to use JDBC4PreparedStatement with a MySQL stored procedure expecting an OUT parameter?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to call a stored procedure from Java using JDBC4PreparedStatement. The stored procedure takes in two input parameters and one output. I set the two input parameters by calling `preparedStatement.setString(index, param)`

but I tried the same for the output and get this error: 
`OUT or INOUT argument 3 for routine db.deleteItem is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger`

Is there a specific type I need to use? If so, how do I set it? I couldn't find any good examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a prepared statement for that, but a callable statement instead. You can consider a callable statement a prepared statement with extra features to support stored procedures (including things like `OUT` parameters).

To register out parameters, you can use [`CallableStatement.registerOutParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter-int-int-).

Answer (score 0):

When we mark parameters as `OUT` or `INOUT`, the expectation is that the SP should be able to work with these parameters and at the same time it should be a Variable instead of a value. This variable then can be used at a later point in time.

A value for an OUT / INOUT parameter to the SP doesn't make much sense as the SP can't manipulate the value and hence the error. We just can pass values for IN parameters alone.

You can refer to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/call.html) documentation here which states:

> To get back a value from a procedure using an OUT or INOUT parameter, pass the parameter by means of a user variable, and then check the value of the variable after the procedure returns. (If you are calling the procedure from within another stored procedure or function, you can also pass a routine parameter or local routine variable as an IN or INOUT parameter.)

So, what you can do is something similar to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751707/mysql-not-a-variable-or-new-pseudo-variable-message)!

```
CALL alextest10 ('p99', 'Madeuppy', '999', 'w9', @a_message);
SELECT @a_message;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: helpful, and I am able to do this in SQL. I am trying to see how I can assign an INOUT parameter from PreparedStatement, but it looks like it does not support it and CallableStatement does.