# What is the purpose of OUT in MySQL stored procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures, out-parameters

What is the purpose of `OUT` in MySQL stored procedures?

If I have a simple stored procedure which looks like this:

````sql
DELIMITER $$
    
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_routine`(
    IN iID int
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = iID;
END

This would give me all the results I want by running:

```sql
CALL new_routine(7);
````

So why would I want/need to use `OUT`?

```sql
DELIMITER $$
    
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_routine`(
    IN iID int,
    OUT vName varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT name INTO vName FROM table1 WHERE id = iID;
END
```

And, call it like this

```sql
CALL new_routine(7, @name);
SELECT @name;
```

Which will give me just the name instead of everything from the rows returned?

I've tried Googling, but clearly haven't asked Google the right question to get a clear answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, you're right, with that second call you will now only get the name itself.

Out-Parameters for many people are generally considered bad practice, but they can be handy if you want a value that you can work with after the call (which could also be calculated by a function obviously). And in most cases there is a better way to achieve what you want without using out-parameters.

However the only "advantage" if you will is that you have a value in a variable instead of a result set which might seem more handy if you decide to use only that value further in your sql or whereever you want to work with it.

So in most cases you should really not use out-parameters, use functions instead.
If you have procedures that return result sets AND out-parameters try to break them down into smaller functions/procedures to avoid out-parameters, because it's just not nice to read and maintain ;)

Answer (score 7):

As quoted from MySQL doc on [**`PROCEDURE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

> For each OUT or INOUT parameter, pass a user-defined variable in the
>   CALL statement that invokes the procedure so that you can obtain its
>   value when the procedure returns. If you are calling the procedure
>   from within another stored procedure or function, you can also pass a
>   routine parameter or local routine variable as an IN or INOUT
>   parameter.

---

And later, an example:

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> delimiter ;
```

---

```
mysql> CALL simpleproc(@a);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> SELECT @a;
+------+
| @a   |
+------+
| 3    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So that is CALL passing back if OUT and INOUT are not used? Isn't it passing back values without using OUT and INOUT? For example, the first stored procedure in my question is not using an OUT or INOUT, but the CALL is getting passed back values? I don't get it.

Comment: @oshirowanen Perhaps I misinterpreted your question. Can you please explain. `IN` is like passing a value to function/procedure. `OUT` will only be used in `PROCEDURE` and you can use it to return custom data. `INOUT` works both ways.

Comment: Basically, I don't understand why `OUT` exists if a CALL receives back data without having to use `OUT`.

Answer (score 2):

Some documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html maybe it will help, quote:

> To get back a value from a procedure using an OUT or INOUT parameter,
>   pass the parameter by means of a user variable, and then check the
>   value of the variable after the procedure returns. (If you are calling
>   the procedure from within another stored procedure or function, you
>   can also pass a routine parameter or local routine variable as an IN
>   or INOUT parameter.) For an INOUT parameter, initialize its value
>   before passing it to the procedure. The following procedure has an OUT
>   parameter that the procedure sets to the current server version, and
>   an INOUT value that the procedure increments by one from its current
>   value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p (OUT ver_param VARCHAR(25), INOUT incr_param INT)
BEGIN
  # Set value of OUT parameter
  SELECT VERSION() INTO ver_param;
  # Increment value of INOUT parameter
  SET incr_param = incr_param + 1;
END;
```

Comment: So that is CALL passing back if OUT and INOUT are not used? Isn't it passing back values without using OUT and INOUT? For example, the first stored procedure in my question is not using an OUT or INOUT, but the CALL is getting passed back values? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

An `OUT` parameter:

- can return the value from a procedure to the caller with [a user-defined session variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).
- cannot accept a raw value without using a user-defined session variable from the caller.
- cannot get any value from the caller because the initial value of an `OUT` parameter is always `NULL` within the procedure.

*[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278392/what-is-a-procedure-in-mysql/77517648#77517648) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579058/inout-parameter-for-a-mysql-procedure/77525443#77525443) explains an `IN` and `INOUT` parameters respectively and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) explains an `OUT` parameter.

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num int
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `2` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (2);
```

Now, you can create `addition(OUT result INT)` procedure which adds `3` to `num` and returns `num` value `5` with `result` to the caller as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addition(OUT result INT)
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + 3;
SELECT num INTO result FROM test;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you can call `addition(@r)` with [CALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html) statement, then `3` is added to `num` and the user-defined session variable e.g. `@r` has `num` value `5` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> CALL addition(@r);
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  5   |
+------+
...
mysql> SELECT @r;
+------+
| @r   |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
```

Be careful, passing the raw value `3` to `result` parameter gets [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751707/mysql-not-a-variable-or-new-pseudo-variable-message/77526195#77526195) below because as I say above, an `OUT` parameter cannot accept a raw value without using a user-defined session variable from the caller.

```sql
mysql> CALL addition(3);
ERROR 1414 (42000): OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine apple.addition is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
```

In addition, you can create `addition()` procedure with the user-defined session variable e.g. `@r` and without an `OUT` parameter as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addition()
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + 3;
SELECT num INTO @r FROM test;
END$$        -- ↑↑ Here

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you call `addition()`, then `3` is added to `num` and `@r` has `num` value `5` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> CALL addition();
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  5   |
+------+
...
mysql> SELECT @r;
+------+
| @r   |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
```

Lastly, you create `addition(OUT result INT)` procedure which adds `result` to `num` and returns `num` value with `result` to the caller as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addition(OUT result INT)
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + result;
SELECT num INTO result FROM test;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But, the caller cannot pass `3` of `@r` to `result` parameter, then `NULL` is added to `num` and `@r` has `num` value `NULL` even if `3` is set to `@r` as shown below because as I say above, an `OUT` parameter cannot get any value from the caller because the initial value of an `OUT` parameter is always `NULL` within the procedure:

```sql
mysql> SET @r = 3;
...
mysql> CALL addition(@r);
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
...
mysql> SELECT @r;
+------+
| @r   |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

So in this case, you can use an `INOUT` parameter like `addition(INOUT result INT)` instead of an `OUT` parameter to add `result` to `num` and to return `num` value with `result` to the caller as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addition(INOUT result INT)
BEGIN
UPDATE test SET num = num + result;
SELECT num INTO result FROM test;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, the caller can pass `3` of `@r` to `result` parameter, then `3` is added to `num` and `@r` has `num` value `5` as shown below because with a user-defined session variable, an `INOUT` parameter can get the value from the caller, then return the value from a procedure to the caller:

```sql
mysql> SET @r = 3;
...
mysql> CALL addition(@r);
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|   5  |
+------+
...
mysql> SELECT @r;
+------+
| @r   |
+------+
|   5  |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of the OUT keyword is stated in the following article

[13.2.1. CALL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html)

> CALL can pass back values to its caller using parameters that are
>   declared as OUT or INOUT parameters.

Comment: So that is CALL passing back if OUT and INOUT are not used?  Isn't it passing back values without using OUT and INOUT?  For example, the first stored procedure in my question is not using an OUT or INOUT, but the CALL is getting passed back values?  I don't get it.