# "Error #1313 RETURN is only allowed in a FUNCTION" When Creating a Stored Procedure in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, mysql-error

I'm trying to create the following stored procedure in phpMyAdmin. But, I keep getting this error: `#1313 - RETURN is only allowed in a FUNCTION`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE pX DECIMAL(19,16);
DECLARE pY DECIMAL(19,16);
DECLARE ls LINESTRING;
DECLARE poly1 POINT;
DECLARE poly1X DECIMAL(19,16);
DECLARE poly1Y DECIMAL(19,16);
DECLARE poly2 POINT;
DECLARE poly2X DECIMAL(19,16);
DECLARE poly2Y DECIMAL(19,16);
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE result INT(1) DEFAULT 0;
SET pX = X(p);
SET pY = Y(p);
SET ls = ExteriorRing(poly);
SET poly2 = EndPoint(ls);
SET poly2X = X(poly2);
SET poly2Y = Y(poly2);
SET n = NumPoints(ls);
WHILE i<n DO
SET poly1 = PointN(ls, (i+1));
SET poly1X = X(poly1);
SET poly1Y = Y(poly1);
IF ( ( ( ( poly1X <= pX ) 
&& ( pX < poly2X ) ) || ( ( poly2X <= pX ) 
&& ( pX < poly1X ) ) ) 
&& ( pY > ( poly2Y - poly1Y ) * ( pX - poly1X ) / ( poly2X - poly1X ) + poly1Y ) ) THEN
SET result = !result;
END IF;
SET poly2X = poly1X;
SET poly2Y = poly1Y;
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
RETURN result;
END//
```

How do I solve this problem? In the SQL pane, I remembered to change the delimiter to // .

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is - you can't use `RETURN` in a `PROCEDURE`. Create a `FUNCTION` instead (`CREATE FUNCTION`), which can return a value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION <FunctionName> RETURNS <DataType>
```

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks so much for the help. Your explanation made the fix really easy.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1313 (42000): RETURN is only allowed in a FUNCTION

When I created the procedure with [RETURN statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/return.html#:%7E:text=The%20RETURN%20statement%20terminates%20execution,procedures%2C%20triggers%2C%20or%20events.) as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(INOUT value INT) 
BEGIN
RETURN 2 + value;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

So, I replaced `RETURN` statement with [SELECT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) as shown below, then I could create the procedure without error:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(INOUT value INT) 
BEGIN
-- RETURN 2 + value;
SELECT 2 + value INTO value;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```