# how to update two table which is having multiple column in stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

As Below code `PersonID` is **primary key** in one table and foreign key in another table i have written this code in php

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE employee SET Firstname = '$fname', Lastname ='$lname', email_id ='$email', Mobile_no ='$mobile', city='$city'  WHERE PersonID = '$userid'");
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE experience SET Company_name = '$com', Location ='$local', Year_Of_Experience ='$year', Description ='$description'  WHERE PersonID = '$userid'");
```

Now i want to write above code in sp any one have any idea how to write?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278392/beginners-guide-to-stored-procedures-with-mysql

Comment: If you are using transactional database like Innodb, you can use transaction (begin, and commit)

Comment: i have same ID multiple time in t.2 but it is only one time in t.1. Can we do update ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run this below in your PHPMyAdmin and use it

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    PROCEDURE DATABASE_NAME.`update_sp`(IN PersonID DATATYPE(size),IN Firstname DATATYPE(size), IN Lastname DATATYPE(size), IN email_id DATATYPE(size), IN Mobile_no DATATYPE(size), IN city DATATYPE(size),
                            IN Location  DATATYPE(size), IN Year_Of_Experience DATATYPE(size), IN Description DATATYPE(size))
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
    BEGIN
        UPDATE employee SET Firstname = REPLACE(Firstname,"'","`"), Lastname =REPLACE(Lastname,"'","`"), email_id =REPLACE(email_id,"'","`"), 
        Mobile_no =REPLACE(Mobile_no,"'","`"), city=REPLACE(city,"'","`")  WHERE PersonID = REPLACE(PersonID,"'","`");

        UPDATE experience SET Company_name = REPLACE(Company_name,"'","`") , Location =REPLACE(Location,"'","`") , Year_Of_Experience =REPLACE(Year_Of_Experience,"'","`") ,
         Description =REPLACE(Description,"'","`")   WHERE PersonID = REPLACE(PersonID,"'","`") ;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can call it as like a function call by passing the arguments ..

Comment: i have same ID multiple time in t.2 but it is only one time in t.1. Can we do update ???

Comment: did you change the SP as per your database and need ? change DB name,User then try it. other wise it will give you error.