# Are procedures atomic in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, atomic, procedure

As the title says, are procedures atomic in MySQL? i.e. would something like

```
for (..)
  <check_if_row_has_flag>
for (..)
  <update_row>
```

work atomically?

Interestingly, I couldn't find much about this on Google except one forum thread from 2009.

Comment: Unless you use transactions - No.

Comment: @PM77-1, *even if* you use transactions, no.

Comment: If "*atomic*" means "*all or none*" then transactions will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, stored procedures are not atomic.

The pseudocode you show above has a race condition. The first loop, checking if a row has a flag, would return an answer, but unless you do a [locking read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), another concurrent session could change the flag immediately after your procedure reads the row.

This is the effect of **optimistic locking**. Rows are not locked until you issue a statement to lock them. So even within a transaction, you don't have atomic locking.

The atomicity that MySQL supports is for transaction commit. Transactions are atomic in that all changes made during the transaction succeed, or else all are rolled back. Other sessions cannot see your transaction in a partially-complete state.

---

Re the comments below:

You can call a procedure within a transaction from your app:

```
START TRANSACTION;
CALL MyProcedure();
COMMIT;
```

You can even start and commit a transaction (or multiple transactions serially), explicitly in the body of a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure()
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    ...UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, blah blah...
    COMMIT;
END
```

But the procedure itself does not implicitly start or commit a transaction.

Comment: So am I right in saying that stored procedures don't guarantee even transaction commit level atomicity?

Comment: No, that's not right. If you start a transaction and run your procedure, the changes made within that procedure are part of the transaction, and then you can commit and all those changes will be committed atomically.

Comment: But stored procedures by themselves don't make any guarantees correct?

Comment: Correct. Stored procedures may run within the scope of a transactions, under control of the calling app. But they do not implicitly start and commit a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a [procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) is not atomic while a [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) is atomic in MySQL. ***Atomic** means rollback occurs if there is error and we can use [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) in a procedure while we cannot in a function.

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num int
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `2` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (2);
```

Now, you create `my_proc()` procedure which updates `num` to `5`, then causes error by [SIGNAL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html) as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc() 
BEGIN
  UPDATE test SET num = 5;
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, calling `my_proc()` gets the error but `num` is not rollbacked to `2` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> CALL my_proc();
ERROR 1644 (45000): An error occurred
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
```

Actually, you can use a transaction outside `my_proc()` to rollback `num` to `2` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974325/mysql-transaction-within-a-procedure/77668946#77668946) explains how to use a transaction inside `my_proc()` to rollback `num` to `2`:

```sql
BEGIN;
CALL my_proc();
ROLLBAKC;
```

Next, you create `my_func()` function which updates num to 5, then causes error by `SIGNAL` statement as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  UPDATE test SET num = 5;
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
  RETURN NULL;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` gets the error, then `num` is rollbacked to `2` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT my_func();
ERROR 1644 (45000): An error occurred
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
```