# Two SELECT statments into one SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Ill try to make it easyer to understand

I have two tables:

```
posts
    id
    title
    descr
    body
    cat_id

cats
    id
    name
```

To get everything from table posts I used this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id"; 
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$posts = $query->fetchAll();
```

Now to get category name for each post from cat_id I used

```
'SELECT c.name FROM cats c INNER JOIN posts p ON c.id = p.cat_id ORDER BY p.id DESC';
```

I want to combine these two querys so I can display category name insted of cat_id (for example instead of Sports I get 1 where category should be displayed).

To display everything from posts after that I used for example

```
    foreach($posts as $post):
 <?php echo $post['title']; ?>
```

And when I use this I cant display category name only cat_id.

I tried UNION and I tried making two querys but cant use foreach in foreach I got error.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into JOINs instead of UNION. Union expects the queries to return the same number of columns. Joins allows you to get related information from multiple tables.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  In general, you should probably stick with having a single expression return a single result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff While it would be nice to have a full set of sample data, this question is answerable from the given information. If sample data and desired results are given, the answer can be modified to take those into account.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you're directly asking. Each `SELECT` statement is a unique query that returns results from the database driver that you would get via `fetchAll()` as you wrote above. (note that there are other ways to get values from a database in PHP, such as `fetch()` as described in https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php. If you don't need the entire set of results in one big list you might consider using that method)

What the other commenter said is correct, what you want to do is:

```sql
SELECT c.title
FROM cats c
INNER JOIN posts p ON c.id = p.cat_id
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

This will give you all the names of `cats` that have an associated `post`. You can use this in the following way:

```php
<?php
$sql = "see above SELECT";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$categoryTitles = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($categoryTitles as $title) {
    echo $title['title'];
}
```

(note that the example will output a big block of text to a browser, you will need to integrate this into your own HTML generation code)

The code you posted:

```php
    foreach($posts as $post):
 <?php echo $post['title']; ?>
```

does not look like entirely valid PHP. The `foreach` looks like it is outside of a `<?php ... ?>` block. And if it were inside of one of those blocks, you would be nesting PHP blocks like: `<?php foreach($posts as $post) { <?php echo $post['title']; ?> } ?>` which I don't think is valid syntax. Also you put a `:` after the `foreach` which I'm not sure is valid syntax either. Your example code is also selecting the `name` column from the database, instead of the `title` column which you are attempting to retrieve in the PHP code.

An example of valid syntax would be:

```php
<?php
// all the PDO code
?>
<!-- some HTML -->
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
  <div> some more HTML </div>
  <? echo $post['title']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The other way to do what you are asking about is to convert your SQL code into a stored procedure, but that is likely too complex for your current use case. (if you wish to learn more about stored procedures in MySQL, take a look at the following Stack Overflow answer: [Beginners' guide to stored procedures with MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278392/beginners-guide-to-stored-procedures-with-mysql))

Comment: I left a little more details

Comment: @annieKovach I have updated my answer to take those into account, hopefully the updates help!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your query. Below is my SQL.
In below query you can select all the records from posts and single column i.e. name.

If you want to have all columns then edit it with p.*,c.* or just give *.
So it will fetch all the columns for you.
Hope this answers your query. If not please explain your question bit more.

```
SELECT p.name,c.* FROM cats as c 
INNER JOIN posts as p ON cats.id = posts.cat_id;
```

Comment: didnt work for me i added few more details on the post