# How can I backup a mysql database from Java?

Tags: java, sql, database

How can I backup a MySQL database using a Java program?

Comment: Do you want it to run a external program to do the backup?

Answer (score 17):

execute `mysqldump` from java code

Example:

Backup :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DBNAME > /path/to/location/backup.sql");
```

Restore:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD < /path/to/location/backup.sql");
```

Comment: your restore command needs to be updated. It is "mysql" instead of "mysqldump". There should be no space between "-p" and password. so the command looks like `mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD < /path/to/location/backup.sql`

Comment: For "#1046 - No database selected" see 
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve 
> `mysql -u example_user -p --database=example < ./example.sql`

Answer (score 3):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -uroot -psome_password database_name > /whereever/dump_todays_date.sql");
```

Comment: Just format your answer as code please :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a window version?

This may help:

[how can i backup and restore date from mysql data base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793385/how-can-i-backup-and-restore-date-from-mysql-data-base)

Answer (score 0):

See this forum, may you get help

http://www.programmingforums.org/thread19446.html