# Using mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I have a website written in html,jsp in eclipse using apache tomcat and mysql 5.5 for the users database.
I need for this school project to export the database into XML file. I'm using:

> mysqldump a1 members -u root -p12345678 --xml > c:\Project\MysqlToXML.xml

and it's working fine. The only problem is that whenever I need to export to XML by using mysqldump I need to 'leave' the website and put the code in the terminal.

I need a way to use this command, within the website. Like to press a button and it will preform the command and will export it as XML file..
Right now if it matters to insert commands to mysql within the website I use

> db.insertUpdateDelete(~sql statment~);

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be able to run the mysqldump program from within one of yours jsp files. I don't know how your project is structured, so I'll just propose a not so nice, but simple solution.

Create a backup.jsp file that runs the mysqldump program. You can read and see a code example about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283168/how-can-i-backup-a-mysql-database-from-java) or [here](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com.ar/2011/07/executing-mysqldump-from-java-and.html).

Then, from one of your jsp of html files create a link () to the backup.jsp file.

I hope this is for maintenance use only, and no end user will have access to this, as it may take some time according to the database size.

Comment: Thanks alot! if it works it would be great! and it's for no more than 3 users.. it's for school project :)

Comment: @Christian I guess that as long as you have the mysqldump within the system PATHs it will work on all kind of OS. Or do you have to switch between different OS?

Comment: @nexus As you said, as long as you have it in your path, it should work on all OS.

Comment: @nexus in my home computer i'm using ubuntu, the school's computers run on windows XP.. i guess I can modify it each time I move..

Comment: @Kristal as long as you have mysqldump within the system PATHs that shouldn't be needed.