# 1046 - No database selected about trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm try to use **trigger** on mysql to replicate user on the same server but with different database.
 **That my request SQL :**

```
 
    CREATE TRIGGER `insert_user_from_test1`  AFTER INSERT ON `wordpress_test1`.`wp_users`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `wordpress_test2`.`wp_users` (
    ID,
    user_login,
    user_pass,
    user_nicename,
    user_email,
    user_url,
    user_registered,
    user_activation_key,
    user_status,
    display_name
    )
    VALUES (
    New.ID, New.user_login, New.user_pass, New.user_nicename, New.user_email, 
    New.user_url, New.user_registered, New.user_activation_key, New.user_status, 
    New.display_name
    );
    END;
```

**And i get that error :**

```
 

    #1046 - No database selected
```

Comment: Please ref to [Error 1046 No database Selected, how to resolve?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing that trigger by executing mysql from the command line tool and haven't selected the database/schema, then you need to specify/select the database/schema first.

So try first executing this command:

```
use your_database_name;
```

Also you can try to specify the database/schema name along with the trigger name:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `your_database_name`.`insert_user_from_test1`.....
```