# Error Number: 1046 No database selected - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When I load my model to run the sql file in codeigniter. I get a error saying no database selected but there is. The error occurs when I click my button to go to the next stage. It some how needs to load database first before load sql. Not to sure on how to make it work.

if I refresh page it loads. Should not have to refresh page should be done as soon as click on button

Error

```
Error Number: 1046
No database selected
CREATE TABLE `country` ( `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL, `iso_code_2` varchar(2) NOT NULL, `iso_code_3` varchar(3) NOT NULL, `address_format` text NOT NULL, `postcode_required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL, `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ‘1’, PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

On Controller

```
$data['button_continue'] = $this->lang->line('button_continue');
$data['button_back'] = $this->lang->line('button_back');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
    $this->load->view('template/step_3', $data);
} else {
    $this->load->model('install/model_install');            
    $this->model_install->database_install();
    $this->model_install->database_connect();
    $this->model_install->dump_sql();
    redirect('step_4');

}
```

Model

```
public function dump_sql() {
      $file = APPPATH . 'modules/install/config/database.sql';
        if (!file_exists($file)) { 
            exit('Could not load sql file: ' . $file); 
        }
        $lines = file($file);   
        if ($lines) {
                $sql = '';
        foreach($lines as $line) {
            if ($line && (substr($line, 0, 2) != '--') && (substr($line, 0, 1) != '#')) {
            $sql .= $line;
            if (preg_match('/;\s*$/', $line)) {
                $sql = str_replace("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `", "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" . $this->input->post('dbprefix'), $sql);
                $sql = str_replace("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `", "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $this->input->post('dbprefix'), $sql);
                $sql = str_replace("CREATE TABLE `", "CREATE TABLE `" . $this->input->post('dbprefix'), $sql);
                $sql = str_replace("INSERT INTO `", "INSERT INTO `" . $this->input->post('dbprefix'), $sql);            
                $this->db->query($sql);
                $sql = '';
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you loading your database from in your CI installation? In the controller? In the model? Are you auto-loading it? Show all of your controller and model please.

Comment: Yes I have a model. I have added the model function to the first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell MySQL which database to use before you create your table.
There is a similar question here: [Error 1046 No database Selected, how to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have set db settings in application/config/database.php

```
$db['default'] = array('hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'your_database_name',
```

Above settings are fine, if you are running locally.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own issue. After doing some more research I found out the reason why I had issue was because I had set database on auto load.

In my controller to fix problem I added $this->load->database and included my sql model function.

This way now loads my sql file so now all solved.

**On my controller function index()**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
    $this->load->view('template/step_3', $data);
} else {
    $this->load->model('install/model_install'); 
    $this->model_install->database_install();           
    if($this->load->database()) {
        $this->model_install->dump_sql();
        redirect('step_4');
        }  else {
           echo "Could Not Load SQL File"; die;
    }
}
```

On My Model

```
public function dump_sql() {
      $file = APPPATH . 'modules/install/config/database.sql';
        if (!file_exists($file)) { 
            exit('Could not load sql file: ' . $file); 
        }
        $lines = file($file);   
        if ($lines) {
                $sql = '';
        foreach($lines as $line) {
            if ($line && (substr($line, 0, 2) != '--') && (substr($line, 0, 1) != '#')) {
            $sql .= $line;
            if (preg_match('/;\s*$/', $line)) {
                $sql = str_replace("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `", "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" . $this->input->post('dbprefix'), $sql);
                $sql = str_replace("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `", "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $this->input->post('dbprefix'), $sql);
                $sql = str_replace("CREATE TABLE `", "CREATE TABLE `" . $this->input->post('dbprefix'), $sql);
                $sql = str_replace("INSERT INTO `", "INSERT INTO `" . $this->input->post('dbprefix'), $sql);            
                $this->db->query($sql);
                $sql = '';
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs as a result of the dsn database format being used on Your Code. I experienced such an error when the dsn was not specified correctly what I mean is this: If you are using pdo driver and connecting to mysql database the dsn will be:

```
$db['bank_sys'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname=dba_bank_sys',
```

The dbname is what is used when referring to mysql but is you are using something like say sqlsrv as your driver then teh dsn will change

```
$db['bank_sys'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'sqlsrv:hostname=localhost;database=dba_bank_sys',
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not the problem wth your code.
You can resolve this DB error by simply add database name in  'database.php'`(C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\config)`-the code is somthing like this  `$db['default']['database'] = 'databasename';`

And you should also do one more thing to resolve this error add another single line in 'autoload.php' `(C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\config)`-the code is somthing like this  `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`