# Show function definition in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sql-function, mysql-function

I am working with existing project, and I am found a sql query with sql-function like

```sql
SELECT * FROM money WHERE  amount = float_convert(0.1);
```

This Query is Working Properly, But I want to see and edit the function `float_convert()`.

I am already tried `SHOW FUNCTION STATUS;`.

It's only showing functions status, I need to view the function definition.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-function-code.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SHOW CREATE FUNCTION float_convert
```

or

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW float_convert
```

perhaps ?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the [CREATE FUNCTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) statement with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-function.html) explains the SQL below and [\G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648967600) can show it more clearly and you must select a database when showing the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve/77491814#77491814):

```sql
SHOW CREATE FUNCTION <function_name>;
```

Or:

```sql
SHOW CREATE FUNCTION <function_name>\G
```