# How to avoid error 1046 when creating tables for a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I need this database in MySQL but I do not understand why I get an error.

```
Create table SalarioBase(
IdSalario number constraint pk_salariobase primary key,
Salario number)
```

/

```
create table Puestos(
IdPuesto number constraint pk_puestos primary key,
NombrePuesto varchar2(20),
SalarioB constraint fk1_puestos references salariobase)
```

/

```
Create table Departamentos(
IdDepartamento number constraint pk_departamento primary key,
NombreDepartamento varchar2(30))
```

/

```
Create table Empleados(
IdEmpleado number constraint pk_empleados primary key,
NombreEmpleado varchar2(30),
PorcAdicional number,
PagoXPunto number,
Puesto constraint fk1_empleados references puestos,
Departamento constraint fk2_empleados references departamentos)
```

/

```
Create table Cursos(
IdCurso number constraint pk_cursos primary key,
NombreCurso varchar2(20),
Puntos number)
```

/

```
Create table EmpleadosCursos(
Empleado constraint fk1_empleadoscursos references empleados,
Curso constraint fk2_empleadoscursos references cursos,
constraint pk_empleadoscursos primary key(empleado,curso),
fecha date)
```

/

```
create table Planillas(
IdPlanilla number,
fecha date,
empleado constraint fk1_planillas references empleados,
salario number,
constraint pk_planillas primary key(idplanilla,empleado,fecha))
```

/

Gives me an error that says error 1046

Comment: What is the error text that accompanies "error 1046"?

Comment: MySQL error 1046 is: "No database Selected".  It's because he's using create statements without defining which database.  Solve it by running `USE your_db_name;` first

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the database before creating the table.
To create database table

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name
```

If you already created database

```
USE database_name
```

For reference check this link
[Error 1046 No database Selected, how to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve)

Comment: @Yury - Why should this be a new question? This is definitly an answer to the question.