# MySQL view existing event script

Tags: sql, mysql, database, events, mysql-event

**MySQL Events**

I have a server with existing events.
I know how to list them, but I don't know what they do.
is there a way to see the event script of existing events?
Either in `cli` or in the `Workbench`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use MySQL's [show create event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-event.html) statement to see the `create event` statement including its body containing the event code.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the [CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) statement with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-event.html) explains the SQL below and [\G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html#idm45689648967600) can show it more clearly and you must select a database when showing the `CREATE EVENT` statement otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve/77491814#77491814):

```sql
SHOW CREATE EVENT <event_name>;
```

Or:

```sql
SHOW CREATE EVENT <event_name>\G
```