# ERROR 1046:No database selected

Tags: mysql, sql

I would  like  to create a SQL database  but this error occurs I do not know why. Can somebody  help  me?

My SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE 'users'(
    'user_id' int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'username' varchar (255) DEFAULT NULL,
    'password' varchar (255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('user_id')
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: How are you trying to run this SQL?

Comment: To select the correct database (MySQL can manage many databases under one MySQL instance) use the `USE \`databasename\`;` before the Create

Comment: Also you are using single quotes around the table name, that wont work use backtick instead. `CREATE TABLE \`users\`(`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 1046 No database Selected, how to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve)

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly,it helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to tell MySQL which database you would like to use to create a table:

```
USE your_database_name;
```

If your database does not exist yet, you have to create one:

```
CREATE DATABASE your_database_name;
```

then tell MySQL that you want to use it:

```
USE your_database_name;
```

and then you can create a table.

Hope it will help you to solve this problem :)

Comment: I am glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Select the database first using: 
`USE database_name`

If you haven't created database, create it by using :

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name
```

and select database using :

```
USE database_name
```

Now, you can create table as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE users(
user_id int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar (255) DEFAULT NULL,
password varchar (255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Primary key should be `user_id` instead of `id` in your case.
I hope, this will help you.

Comment: Thanks,it worked . And  I'M sorry ,I did a typo with this user_id,thanks  for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

go to Manage User Privileges on cpanel
and let your user access the specified database!