# MYSQL Join tables where second table is used in multiple columns on table 1

Tags: mysql

So i have a table 1, named Meals and here are the column names I have.

mealName, ingredient1, ingredient2, ingredient3, ingredient4, ingredient5

the ingredient columns are all numbers that are linked to the second table. It is just one table that has the column names ingredientId and ingredient.

I want to display the mealName and the actual ingredient from the second table, but i can't get it to display the secondary ingredients.

This works just to display ingredient1, but I need all 5.

```
SELECT mealName
     , hearts
     , i.ingredient 
  FROM Meals m
  JOIN Ingredients i 
    ON i.ingredientId = m.ingredient1;
```

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: I'm not going to this restaurant

Comment: If meal has 6 ingredients, you are screwed.

Comment: You better change your table structure.  This is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: It's just for a video game application that I'm working. Its like a helper for the game. This query is used in a windows form i'm using to add more to the database myself. No one other than me will ever see this query or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your existing schema, you will need to join `Meals` to `Ingredients` 5 times:

```
SELECT mealName,
    hearts,
    i1.*,
    i2.*,
    i3.*,
    i4.*,
    i5.*,
FROM Meals m
    INNER JOIN Ingredients i1
        ON m.ingredient1 = i1.ingredientId
    INNER JOIN Ingredients i2
        ON m.ingredient2 = i2.ingredientId
    INNER JOIN Ingredients i3
        ON m.ingredient3 = i3.ingredientId
    INNER JOIN Ingredients i4
        ON m.ingredient4 = i4.ingredientId
    INNER JOIN Ingredients i5
        ON m.ingredient5 = i5.ingredientId
```

But what happens if a meal has more then 5 ingredients?

A much better approach would be to have 3 tables: `Meals`, `Ingredients`, and `MealIngredients`.

The `Meals` table would be:

```
id, meal_name, hearts
```

The `MealIngredients` table would be:

```
meal_id, ingredient_id
```

Ingredients would stay the same.

Then you would just need to join the three tables together:

```
SELECT m.name,
    i.ingredient
FROM Meals m
    INNER JOIN MealIngredients mi
        ON m.id = mi.meal_id
    INNER JOIN Ingredients i
        ON mi.ingredient_id = i
```

Comment: There wont ever be more than 5 ingredients.

Comment: Tried your first way, and i get the error code 1046.

Comment: Regardless, from a database design standpoint having another table to hold a one/many-to-many relationship (one meal has many ingredients) should be stored in another table.

Comment: I didn't write out the full query, I left that for you to implement. But I will update

Comment: Yeah, I finished it out and I still get the 1046 error

Comment: That is because you do not have a database selected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve

Comment: i figured it out. Just had to have the database name and then .Ingredient or .Meals after it

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple JOINS in a single statement. In order to join one table multiple times however, you have to give the duplicate table a new alias each time (AFAIK) as if it was a unique table.

The query should look something like this:

```
SELECT mealName, i1.ingredient, i2.ingredient, i3.ingredient, i4.ingredient, i5.ingredient
FROM Meals m
JOIN Ingredients i1 on m.ingredient1 = i.IngredientId
JOIN Ingredients i2 on m.ingredient2 = i.IngredientId
JOIN Ingredients i3 on m.ingredient3 = i.IngredientId
JOIN Ingredients i4 on m.ingredient4 = i.IngredientId
JOIN Ingredients i5 on m.ingredient5 = i.IngredientId
```

Comment: I get error code 1046

Comment: @LaurenTownsend Have you Googled what error 1046 means?  It has nothing to do with query.