# Why I cannot "insert into" but can "update" mysql table?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, lamp, insert-into

I moved a website from a classic shared hosting server to an AWS server where the LAMP environment is run inside a docker container onto which I map the website pages and DB.

The website is correctly populated with the content provided by the DB, I can correctly update an article from the admin area of the website but I can only add a new row via `INSERT INTO` statement through phpmyadmin console but no longer from the admin area of the website. Everything worked fine before so my guess is that something is preventing my code from inserting a new row in the tables of the database whereas it allows an update.

Anyone ever experienced a similar problem and knows what shall I look for?

I am using [Matt Rayner lamp:latest-1604](https://github.com/mattrayner/docker-lamp) container with Ubuntu 16.04.1, Apache/2-4-18, PHP version 5.6.33 and MySQL 5.0.11
About the AWS instance, it is a t2.micro, cofigured using the tutorials provided by Amazon Web Services Documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Have you check the insert permission for your user ? **SELECT `user`, `host` , insert_priv FROM USER** try this query to get permission

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra on root and admin I have all privileges granted (looking from phpmyadmin).When trying the query from mysql cli I get **error 1046: No database selectedOM USER 777 SELECT ec2-user, localhost**.
I tried with **SELECT ec2-user, localhost, insert_priv FROM USER** but got the sam error. 
When I looked for the list of users with **SELECT User FROM mysql.user**; I got admin, root, mysql.session and mysql. sys.

Comment: could you please first choose the database using **use <databaseName>** and then execute your query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve