# No database selected when import the script

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I created a script using `MySqlWorkbench`, at the top of the script there is this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
USE `contacts` ;
```

when I import this script in `PhpMyAdmin`, I get:

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `contact` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1046 - No database selected

Why the schema `contacts` isn't creating a new database?

Comment: Which version of `mysql` are you using

Comment: Check this : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve)

Comment: Check this : [No databsa selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CREATE TABLE contacts.contact`

(not allowed to comment yet, so forced to use answer.)

Comment: I mean, MySqlWorkbench doesn't add in the script the database creation, how can I tell to MySqlWorkbench to add also CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXIST..

Comment: Do you have  `USE contacts;` after your CREATE SCHEMA?

Comment: Yes, you can see it in my question, the script was generated by MySqlWorkbench