# No database selection error in MySql although the database is exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create a table in products DB. I also *use* command to select the DB; it already exists too. But the following error has occurred and trying to find a solution. [The error occurred in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOaIc.png)

One of the solutions has recommended using the "use" command ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve). I did it too. But still, it is getting error in MySQL.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of images of code and error messages, include them as text in the question.

Comment: Where in the error message does it say anything about the database wasn't existing? It rather seems like you forgot to terminate your statements with a trailing `;`.

Comment: @stickybit yeah I know but it seems to me this img would provide a better understanding of problems.

Comment: As @stickybit has already pointed out: you are missing a semicolon after the use statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a database issue. It seems to be a syntax error for creating table.

Try this

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fruit (........)
```

Please try to add code instead of adding an image.

Comment: No, single quotes around identifiers are wrong syntax. Check: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a3fe6df1a8b2b199293e0dbd86ed1fc9

Comment: @Yugesha sapte, I knew it. But the image would give a better understanding of the problem. Please make sure it is a syntax error.

Comment: @stickybit In another ques the problem was database was not selected that's why the error has occurred. But in my terms, It is not selecting the DB as it has already created.

Comment: Did you try my updated answer? it should solve your issue.

Comment: @Md.Al-mustanjid: Look at the error message you posted: It does not say anything about a missing or not selected database.

Comment: @stickybit while i only give the query 'use products'. showing the following error
'#1046 No database selected"

Comment: @YugeshaSapte I did but still getting error.