# ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected mysql Erro

Tags: mysql-error-1064

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxCVS.jpg)
Under syntax is correct or wrong!! please help ..
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON summy-database.* TO 'sammy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 1046 No database Selected, how to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve)

Comment: Please read this and try to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `-` in the database name, in order to make that work you have to escape it with backticks.

Ex:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `summy-database`.* TO 'ammy'@'localhost';
```

Comment: It's working excellent, thanks Dear @Syco