# "1046 No Database Selected" error when copying sql dump file from EC2 to RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services

From the terminal I am able to login to the sql server and execute commands such as create database and use database etc. However, when I'm executing the following command "mysql -u  -p --host  < Sqlfile.sql", I am receiving the 1046 error. This is an AWS lab environment and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1046 error means you forgot to mention the database name, follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21837551/13126651

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 1046 No database Selected, how to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005409/error-1046-no-database-selected-how-to-resolve)

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you have to specify a database to insert this dumpfile into. The command should look something like this:

```
mysql -u youruser -p database_name < Sqlfile.sql
```

or

```
mysql -u youruser -p --database=database_name < Sqlfile.sql
```